# How can I unlock a self encrypting disk using an sata usb adapter

Tags: hard-disk, encryption

Suppose I plug in a self encrypting disk (for example the samung 840 pro) via a sata usb adapter to a linux-box. Suppose I know the password. How can I access the hard-drive in this case?

Answer (score 2):

Normally you can use `hdparm --security-unlock mypassword` to send the password to the disk to unlock it, but I don't think this works with USB.

Comment: Hm. Thanks. But indeed my adapter seems not to forward all ATA-commands.